# Return Array from function in stock javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

How can I return an array from a function in javasript?

```
  var ConvertedTxtData;
  var SendData;
  ConvertedTxtData = txtdata.split("|");
  ConvertedTxtData.pop();
  //console.log(txtdata);
  //console.log(ConvertedTxtData);
  return ConvertedTxtData;
```

This does not return the array.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: What does it return then?

Comment: @PM77-1  it returns "[object Promise]"

Answer (score 0):

You can `return` an array, but your problem is that the text doesn't have enough splits after it is popped.

```js
function doSomething() {
    let text = 'here|are|some|words';
    let textArray = text.split('|');
    return textArray;
};
doSomething(); //Output ['here','are','some','words']
```

Comment: it does not work
it still returns: "[object Promise]"

Comment: Then use `await`. This has nothing to do with the original question.